# Connecting to a laser with Python's socket interface

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to connect over ethernet to a piece of hardware (a laser) which listens for connections on a certain port.  The laser's documentation on this is very minimal; the entirety of it is as follows:

> Ethernet TCP/IP Interface:
> The IP address of the laser is shown on the front panel. Touching the screen where
> the address is shown displays the network setup menu where you can change the
> network settings.
> The laser listens for connections on port 10001. The command must be sent as a
> single string in a single packet. The individual commands are described in “Interface
> Commands” on page 3-2.

The commands alluded to are a list of few-character text strings, such as "ABN", which turns the laser on.  I would like to talk to the laser using Python's socket interface.  I've tried to follow the pattern of [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/), but to no avail.  Here's an example of what I tried:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.223",10001))
s.sendall(b"ABN")
```

This does nothing.   However, I can talk to the laser using Putty and a raw connection to the same IP and port as above.  This opens a terminal where I can type commands such as "ABN" (which works, turning the laser on) and read the laser's replies.

**Question:**  What is a Putty "raw" connection doing, and how can I replicate it with Python?

---

Edit: The laser is an IPG YLR-100-1064-LP-WC.

Comment: I also appreciate references for where to read up on this.  I've been perusing "Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach" by Kurose and Ross, which is helpful, but hasn't answered my questions yet.  Perhaps I just haven't read far enough though...

Comment: Have you tried sending a newline or a CRLF? Like `b"ABN\n"` or `b"ABN\r\n"` or `b"DESTROY Omicron Persei 8\r\n"`?

Comment: What about answering your own question? Anyway it will be more useful question if you provide the laser model.

Answer (score 0):

A commenter suggested I add "\r\n" to the end of the text string I send to the laser.  This worked--I can now communicate with the laser.